# PHPExcel - how to insert a row object

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to find the row where A column is '1', then copy it to another sheet. Now I can get matches rows object, but how to use the objects insert to another sheet with all column style and value? (style means width, height, background color ... etc)

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() => $row) {
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $column => $cell) {
        if ($column == 'A' && $cell->getValue() == '1') {
            // how to insert this row object to sheet index 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator() => $row) {
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $column => $cell) {
        if ($column == 'A' && $cell->getValue() == '1') {
            // how to insert this row object to sheet index 1
            $activeSheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
            $activeSheet->setCellValue("CELL_INDEX","VALUE");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the code below will work for you. I have not tested it but I think this kind of logic will work. Try it out.

```
$row_index = 1;
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();
foreach ($rowIterator as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $column => $cell) {
        if ($column == 'A' && $cell->getValue() == '1') {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1); //Set index to sheet at position 1
            foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $column => $cell) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$row_index, $cell->getValue()); //Write the data of the row to sheet 1
            }
            $row_index++;
            break; //Break and check the next row.
        }

    }
}
```